# How to get all the array indexes that meet a condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to create a method that works like `Array.prototype.findIndex` but that returns all the indexes that match the condition:

```
  Array.prototype.which = function(condition) {
    let result = this.reduce((acc, x, i, arr) => {
      if (condition) { acc.push(i) }
      return acc
    }, [])
    return result
  }
```

So that I could do:

```
  [ 'a', null, 'b' ].which(x => x !== null) // [0, 2]
```

This doesn't work because I don't know how to link the `x` argument in the function call with the `x` value inside the `which` function.

Comment: @Paul wouldn't that give me `['a', 'b']` instead of `[0, 2]`?

Comment: @nachocan Yes, never mind.

Comment: @James wouldn't `Array.filter` give me `['a', 'b']` instead of `[0, 2]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the predicate:

```
  Array.prototype.which = function(predicate) {
    let result = this.reduce((acc, x, i, arr) => {
      if (predicate(x)) { acc.push(i) }
      return acc
    }, [])
    return result
  }
```

Comment: stay consistent with the rest of the API: `if(fn.call(ctx,x,i,arr)) ...` and therefore `Array.prototype.which = function which(fn, ctx) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

An old-school for-loop method:

```
Array.prototype.which = function(test) {
    const result = [];
    for(let i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { 
        if (test(this[i])) {
           result.push(i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

While it is easier to make a mistake with for and while, they sometimes offer performance gain because of fewer function calls.

Comment: What's the point of using `const` here aswell as `++i` instead of `i++`?

Comment: @Kinduser `const` here is a hint to the javascript engine that `result` always points to the same object,  as opposed to `let` -- indicating that the bound object may change.  Alternatively, it is a hint to a human reader that we are writing ES6 code as opposed to the common `var` in earlier Javascript.  Prefix/postfix `++i`/`i++` does not matter here, either will work.

Comment: Agreed with `const`, but prefix is misleading here imo. I've edited your post to make it more readable. If you dislike it, just rollback it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer `Array#forEach`.

```js
Array.prototype.which = function(condition) {
    let result = [];
    this.forEach((v,i) => condition(v) ? result.push(i) : null);
    return result;
}

console.log([1,2,3,4,5,6].which(v => v > 3));
```

Comment: Thanks, any specific reason for the preference?

Comment: @nachocab Seems just simplier. I'm not sure about efficiency, I will test it asap.

Comment: @nachocab The efficiency is almost the same in each case.